# Angular 5 query service

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Angular 5 and Firestore, and I have a service where I can get an student by his ID, or all students, but i want to make a method for get a student by his email. I have this service for get a student by his ID:

```
  getStudient(uid: string){
this.studientDoc = this.afs.doc<StudientsInterface>(`studients/${uid}`);
this.studient = this.studientDoc.snapshotChanges().map(action => {
  if (action.payload.exists === false){
    return null;
  }else{
    const data = action.payload.data() as StudientsInterface;
    data.uid = action.payload.id;
    return data;
  }
});
return this.studient;}
```

And this other for call the service:

```
  constructor(private studientService: StudientService){
this.currentStudient = localStorage.getItem('studientEmailLS');
this.studientService.getStudient(this.currentStudient).subscribe(studient => {
  this.studientName = studient.name;
}) }
```

I tried this code, but it don't works:

```
      getStudientByEmail(email: string){
    this.studientDoc = this.afs.doc<StudientsInterface>(`studients/${email}`);
    this.studient = this.studientDoc.snapshotChanges().map(action => {
      if (action.payload.exists === false){
        return null;
      }else{
        const data = action.payload.data() as StudientsInterface;
        data.uid = action.payload.id;
        data.email = action.payload.get(email);
        return data;
      }
    });
    return this.studient;
  }
```

I can retrieve the UID, but I can't see the parameter "email" in my sentence"action.payload.*"

How can I do to call the service with an email and get all object data?

Comment: same as how you did for id

Comment: I added a function then I tried to solve my problem, but it didn't works